# How to name the foreign key constraint of ManyToOne references since JPA 2.1?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

`@org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey` has been deprecated, but I cannot find any examples how the JPA 2.1 equivalent would have to look like?

```
@ManyToOne
@ForeignKey(name = "FK_USER") //@deprecated Prefer the JPA 2.1 introduced {@link javax.persistence.ForeignKey} instead.
private User user;
```

How is this to be implemented without the deprecated annotation?

Comment: Read the documentation, try something: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ForeignKey.html

Answer (score 61, accepted):

As [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ForeignKey.html) indicates, this annotation can't be applied to anything:

> @Target(value={})

It can thus only be used as part of another annotation (listed in the *See Also* section):

```
@JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_USER"))
```

Comment: is it force that we use column name when we specify the foreign key? can't we just pass the field name, and say this field suppose to hold the key for the reference?

Comment: @deadManN You don't pass the column name. You pass the name of the foreign key constraint. And no, you're not forced to specify it. You could have found that by just clicking on the javadoc link...

Answer (score 8):

You're right, I misread the documentation. It can be defined as a part of `@JoinColumn` annotation.

It should look like that:

```
@JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_USER"))
```

Comment: In fact it's not. `The annotation is not allowed for this location`. As I autogenerate my schema by hibernate, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 4):

Do you insert `@JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_USER"))` direct to mapped to entity example:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_USER"))
private User user;
```