# The ForeignKey jpa/hibernate annotation does not work as exptected

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

In the entity there are two pairs of assotications:

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey;
...
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, targetEntity = UserSettingsEntityBean.class)
@JoinColumn(name = INTEGER_USER_ID)
@ForeignKey(name = "FK_USER_TO_SETTINGS")
private UserSettingsEntity userSettings;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = DivisionEntityBean.class, optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "DIVISION_ID", nullable = true, columnDefinition = "integer")
@ForeignKey(name = "FK_USER_TO_DIVISIOG")
private DivisionEntity division;
```

Hibernate generates for these ForeignKey annotations the following updates:
The correct update, as expected:

```
alter table users add constraint FK_USER_TO_DIVISIOG foreign key (DIVISION_ID) references division
```

The wrong db update, the annotation is ignored (constraint name is generated):

```
alter table users add constraint FK_olm1qeb13uc1worutbx1sc22k foreign key (USER_ID) references user_settings
```

Can you explain it? Is there a way to set constraint name in the second case?

**UPDATED1:**

The following solution does not work either:

```
@JoinColumn(name = INTEGER_USER_ID, foreignKey = @javax.persistence.ForeignKey(name = "FK_USER_TO_PERS_DATA"))
```

This solution is for ManyToOne, here is the problem with OneToOne

**UPDATED2:**
[unit test to reproduce this issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9591)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to name the foreign key constraint of ManyToOne references since JPA 2.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23007356/how-to-name-the-foreign-key-constraint-of-manytoone-references-since-jpa-2-1)

Comment: @Vitaly, not, it's not duplicate. It's OneToOne, the solution that is described in your link does not work here.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.persistence.ForeignKey;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne; 

@JoinColumn(updatable = false, nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_customerUser_customer" ))
@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Customer customer;
```

Comment: Whats the version of your JPA/Hibernate?

Comment: How do you come up with this solution?